# Working with RestKit to simultaneously in transient and persistent objects(core data)

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm working on RestKit to store data in Core Data I have done storing them on transient objects. How do I save them parallely in Core Data.

Should I assign PersistentStore to `RKObjectManager` or `NSManagedObjectContext` to `RKObjectManager`.

I have gone through many tutorials each one conflicts from other.
Suggest some clear Tutorial to work on.

After going through github tutorial i have written the following code for mapping data to coredata and transient objects.But it is not working

//assigning the model

```
     NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]         pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType:@"momd"]];
     NSLog(@"sql:%@",[RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sample![enter image description here][1].sqlite"]);
    objectManager=[[RKObjectManager alloc]init];

  // NOTE: Due to an iOS 5 bug, the managed object model returned is immutable.
     NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];
     managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

     objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

     NSError *error;
     [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:[RKApplicationDataDirectory()   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FourthEstateApp.sqlite"] fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
     NSLog(@"sql:%@",[RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FourthEstateApp.sqlite"]);
     [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
```

//creating mapping

```
      storyDataMapping=[RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Story" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
      [storyDataMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                             @"shares",
                                             @"views",
                                             @"weight",
                                             @"story_url",
                                             @"other_articles",
                                             @"color",
                                             @"public_url",
                                             @"images_urls", nil
                                             ]
 ];

    articleDataMapping=[RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Article"   inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [articleDataMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:[
                                               NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"location", @"original_url",
                                               @"publication_date_time", @"title",
                                               @"article_url", @"source_name",
                                               @"source_twitter_id", nil
                                               ]
 ];

[storyDataMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"main_article"
                                                                             t    toKeyPath:@"main_article"
                                                                           withMapping:articleDataMapping]];
responseDescriptorForStoryData = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:storyDataMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                        pathPattern:Nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:
                                 RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[responseDescriptorForStoryData]];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:categoryURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

   RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *objectRequestOperation =  [[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                                               responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptorForStoryData]];
     [objectRequestOperation
     setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
     NSLog(@"Load collection of Articles: %@", mappingResult);

    for (Story *s in mappingResult.array) {
      NSLog(@"storymain article is:%@", s.main_article.title);
      [stories addObject:s];
     }
```

//on success fetching the data from coredata

```
     NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext =[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]init];
     NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Story" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];

      NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
      [request setEntity:entity];


      // Execute the fetch -- create a mutable copy of the result.
      NSError *error = nil;
      NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
      NSLog(@"results from cd:%@ error:%@",mutableFetchResults,error);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"success" object:stories];
  }

                        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                          //RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
                          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"failure" object:error];
                          NSLog(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
                        }
     ];
```

Enter code here

```
   [objectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:objectRequestOperation];
   [objectRequestOperation start];
```

successblock is executed
when I am trying to fetch the data following error is occured

> CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Story'

Comment: Show the code for how you currently create the object manager and managed object store. The RestKit github page has all the information you need.

Comment: Default persistentStore is created when i choosed coredata duding creation of progect

Comment: So did you look at the RestKit github page about how to get RestKit to manage the Core Data stack?

Comment: I read RestKit github page from that i came to know that we should RKObjectManager for transient objects mapping ,RKManagedObjectManager for PersistentStore.Can I save both in persistent and transient for a single request

Comment: You can, that is controlled by the mappings. `RKManagedObjectManager` doesn't exist, you only have `RKObjectManager`. The minimum setup is https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#managed-object-request

Comment: i have a doubt that restkit inserts data into coredata or adds the data to the existing one while mapping

Comment: After reading githubpage on restkit i have written code as

Comment: And? Edit your question with details of your code, how you're testing and the results you see if you still have issues.